# Selenium driver for web app testing on chrome in incognito windows

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, web-application

So I am trying to use a selenium web driver extension on chrome to record a web application test on a chrome browser that is in an incognito mode. How do you run a test on a web application in an incognito mode of google chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

you can't record the browser actions with selenium webdriver. This is possible only with Selenium IDE.

So to answer to you question:

You **can't** make Selenium IDE to open chrome in incognito mode.
If you want to achieve a similar functionality in non incognito mode in chrome using Selenoium IDE you can execute javascript to clear the local storage and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

While working in a software testing services company, I have experienced such requirement i.e. verifying certain scenarios in chrome incognito mode using Selenium Webdriver.
Please find below code snippet working at my end -

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;                                
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;                      
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class IncognitoTestCase {                                     
    public static void main(String[] args){  
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\your_chrome_directory\\chromedriver.exe");                                            
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");        
    options.addArguments("--incognito");                          
    WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options); 
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin");                     
    }                                                                     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium by default runs a clean browser session that gets deleted after test run and that is what incognito mode basically does.

You can, however, force [the mode](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#incognito)

> --incognito:   Forces Incognito mode even if user data directory is specified using the --user-data-dir switch.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
```